# Assigning a character name to a unique numerical identifier in R

Tags: r

I have a data set that uses a Unique number identifier to represent a location. I'm trying to convert that number into the name of that location. My original thought has been to create an if function to either replace or create a new column with the location, but I think I am going about this the wrong way. dummy data below

```
  ID    df1    df2    df3
  1     $500   yes    open
  1     $56    no     close 
  1     $40    no     pend
  2     $65    yes    open 
  3     $600   no     close
  6     $100   no     pend
```

desired output

```
  ID    df1    df2    df3
  HCA   $500   yes    open
  HCA   $56    no     close 
  HCA   $40    no     pend
  LMO   $65    yes    open 
  SAH   $600   no     close
  SEM   $100   no     pend
```

Or

```
  Loc  ID  df1    df2    df3
  HCA  1   $500   yes    open
  HCA  1   $56    no     close 
  HCA  1   $40    no     pend
  LMO  2   $65    yes    open 
  SAH  3   $600   no     close
  SEM  6   $100   no     pend
```

Comment: Where `1=HCA`, `2=LMO` etc... defined ?

Comment: You can convert ID column to factor format

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just use plain `merge` here, assuming you have a data frame which maps `ID` to `Loc`:

```
map <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,6), Loc=c("HCA", "LMO", "SAH", "SEM"),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
result <- merge(df, map, by="ID", all=TRUE)[c("Loc", "df1", "df2", "df3")]
result

  Loc  df1 df2   df3
1 HCA $500 yes  open
2 HCA  $56  no close
3 HCA  $40  no  pend
4 LMO  $65 yes  open
5 SAH $600  no close
6 SEM $100  no  pend
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

We can just use the 'ID' as index (assuming it is `numeric`).

```
df1$ID <- c("HCA", "LMO", "SAH", "", "", "SEM")[df1$ID]
df1$ID
#[1] "HCA" "HCA" "HCA" "LMO" "SAH" "SEM"
```

NOTE: As an input vector, the 4th and 5th elements are left as blank.  If those 'ID's are present in the original dataset, fill those with the corresponding character strings

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
database$ID[database$ID == 1] <- "HCA"
```

Tell me if this solution doesn't work, please.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great package called `data.table`.

Just follow my example:

```
require("data.table")

x = data.table(c(1, 2, 3), c(1000, 2000, 3000))
names = c("A", "B", "C")

set(x, i = NULL, "V1", names)
```

result:

> V1   V2
>
> 1:  A 1000
>
> 2:  B 2000
>
> 3:  D 3000

Comment: was it useful ?